# Binding from external class in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have **TextBlock** binded manually in MainWindow.xaml

```
<TextBlock Name="TestPrice"
                           Height="30"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                           VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                           Text="{Binding Path=
                           ScreenMarketLogger, Mode=Default, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

In **MainWindow.xaml.cs** I define class with properties:

```
public class ScreenLoggerBind : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


            private string _ScreenMarketLogger;
            public string ScreenMarketLogger
            {
                get
                {
                    return _ScreenMarketLogger;
                }
                set
                {
                    _ScreenMarketLogger = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("ScreenMarketLogger");
                }
            }

            private string _CurrentPrice;
            public string CurrentPrice
            {
                get
                {
                    return _CurrentPrice;
                }
                set
                {
                    _CurrentPrice = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("CurrentPrice");
                }
            }

            private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }

            public ScreenLoggerBind()
            {
                this.ScreenMarketLogger = "\r\n begin \r\n";
            }
        }
```

I have another class (physically this is separate file) where I define constructor for **ScreenLoggerBind** class.

```
class ExternalClass
{
...
ScreenLoggerBind ScreenLogger = new ScreenLoggerBind();
...
}
```

Now I transfer **DataContext** into this class like this:

```
 public void Init(MainWindow mw)
        {
            mw.TestPrice.DataContext = ScreenLogger;
        }
```

And call this function in **MainWindow.xaml.cs** in the **mainWindow** method like this

```
ExternalClass ext = new ExternalClass()     
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        ext.Init(this);
    }
```

And if I assign a value to a variable **ScreenLogger.ScreenMarketLogger** I see result on main WPF form.
All works properly here.

Now question. If I create component dynamically in **MainWindow.xaml.cs**, like this for example:

```
    Label lbl_Price = new Label();
    lbl_Price.Name = string.Format("lbl_Price_{0}{1}", i.ToString(), cell.ToString());
    Binding lbl_PriceBinding = new Binding("Content");
    lbl_PriceBinding.Source = ScreenLogger.CurrentPrice;
    lbl_PriceBinding.Mode = BindingMode.Default;
    lbl_PriceBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
    lbl_Price.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, lbl_PriceBinding);
....
```

And define DataContext in external class **ExternalClass.cs**

```
 public void Init(MainWindow mw)
        {
            mw.TestPrice.DataContext = ScreenLogger;
 foreach (Label lbl in mw.ChainGrid.Children.OfType<System.Windows.Controls.Label>())
            {
                if (lbl.Name == "lbl_XName_Price_00")
                {
 lbl.DataContext = ScreenLogger;
                }
            }
        }
```

This is doesn't work! I see created dynamically Label on main form. But if I assign value to **ScreenLogger.CurrentPrice** variable I don't see any changes.

Why? where I made mistake?

Comment: @ASh Hi. Thank you for answer. I know, this is not easy way. But, I should separate it, because of about 5 different classes with thousand lines of code each. And all of this classes can use the same components for data representation. 

What about your advice, this is not decision, because **TextBlock** with **TestPrice** name will be deleted. I created it as example only.

Comment: I would suggest getting few cups of coffee and starting with a nice article about mvvm in wpf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do as below:

```
Binding lbl_PriceBinding = new Binding("CurrentPrice");
lbl_PriceBinding.Source = ScreenLogger;
lbl_PriceBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
```

You must provide the path to property of a source in `Binding` constructor. In your case the source is `ScreenLogger` and path, relative to it, is `CurrentPrice`.